# Non-vectorial illustration to animation, is it possible?

Tags: animation, graphics, adobe-illustrator, video-editing, video-effects

A graphic artist created this illustration: https://www.dreamstime.com/boy-light-ball-looking-fantasy-tree-night-scenery-boy-light-ball-looking-fantasy-tree-digital-art-image100502024 .

Then, someone created an animation out of the illustration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GBfVhmrvhQ&lc=UgwV3DHioL_3ceLfj4J4AaABAg (background animation). Is it possible that someone else (than the original artist) did this animation, without having the vectorial file?

Answer (score 1):

For the illustration, Photoshop is the best tool for this.
For the animation, there are many apps that can make a simple animation from chosen photo, you can search in your phone's app store